# Мобильная версия сайта не фиксирована

Tags: мобильная-разработка

Подскажите пожалуйста, появилась вот такая фишка.
То есть сайт не фиксирован по горизонтали, двигается налево направо.
Для примера,- если увеличить масштаб, а затем  уменьшить, он должен свой истинный размер принять. На самом деле  он уменьшается, как можно увидеть на скрине.
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где примерный код страницы? И если это на всех страницах то можете дать общий `layout`.

Comment: http://altynex.byethost10.com вот ссылка на сайт.Спасибо

Comment: @Dias весь код, достаточный для воспроизведения проблемы, должен быть прямо в тексте вопроса без каких-либо ссылок

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу понять причину возникновения этой проблемы